# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a class variable in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my ViewController class declaration, I have a private variable of type NSDictionary*:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    float fScreenWidth;
    float fScreenHeight;
    float fBasePanelWidth;
    float fToolbarHeight;
    float fLabelAndButtonHeight;
    NSDictionary* fMooDataJson;
}
```

and in my `viewDidLayoutSubviews(…)` method, I assign this to an `NSDictionary` object. However, in other calls, when accessing the variable, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. The access is like this:

```
NSDictionary* subMooList = [fMooDataJson objectForKey:@"moo"];
```

Any ideas why this would fail? Are there better ways of accessing this variable?

Comment: Please show the assignment of `fMooDataJson`.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I ended up making it a property and that did the trick.